# Parent pom not getting updated with UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2 openrewrite recipe?

Tags: java, openrewrite

The openrewrite isn't working on my POM.xml. It's not updating the  Spring version, Java version and pretty much any dependency versions

My application is running JAVA 11 and Spring 2.5.3

The dryRun of openrewrite created a rewrite.patch file without any errors. However, it only contained minimal Java syntax updates. No change to the POM

Here is the POM.xml for reference:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1yPBP0NZ1eLS0YmhmEL0p9wH6wSK6_oZP/view?usp=sharing

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>uk.co.andipari</groupId>
    <artifactId>micrometerV12-tendercontrol-avro-processor</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>

    <name>Micrometer info V12 XML KafkaStream Processor</name>
    <description>Micrometer info V12 XML KafkaStream Processor</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.3</version>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
                <artifactId>testcontainers-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <avro.version>1.10.2</avro.version>
        <protobuf.version>3.17.3</protobuf.version>
        <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>3.0.0</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR12</spring-cloud.version>
        <kafka-avro-serializer.version>6.2.0</kafka-avro-serializer.version>
        <os-maven-plugin.version>1.7.0</os-maven-plugin.version>
        <protobuf.input.directory>${project.basedir}/schema/proto</protobuf.input.directory>
        <build-helper-maven-plugin.version>3.0.0</build-helper-maven-plugin.version>
        <protobuf.output.directory>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources</protobuf.output.directory>
        <testcontainers.version>1.16.0</testcontainers.version>
        <log4j2.version>2.16.0</log4j2.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>confluent</id>
            <name>Confluent</name>
            <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
        </repository>

        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>Confluent</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/JandiparPLC/micrometerprocessor-common-lib</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.andipari</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometerprocessor-common-lib</artifactId>
            <version>5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>uk.co.andipari</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometerschema-V12-tendercontrol</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-function-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.7</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
            <type>test-jar</type>
            <classifier>test-binder</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.micrometer</groupId>
            <artifactId>micrometer-registry-prometheus</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.logstash.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logstash-logback-encoder</artifactId>
            <version>6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
            <artifactId>protobuf-java</artifactId>
            <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.awaitility/awaitility -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.awaitility</groupId>
            <artifactId>awaitility</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.avro/avro -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-streams</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-schema</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>stream-applications-test-support</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-core</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.0-groovy-3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-spring</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>2.0-groovy-3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.groovy/groovy-all -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.groovy</groupId>
            <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
            <version>4.0.17</version>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka</artifactId>
            <version>${testcontainers.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spockframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spock-junit4</artifactId>
            <version>2.0-groovy-3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
            <version>${kafka-avro-serializer.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.kafka/spring-kafka -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.5.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-datatype-jsr310</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.xml.bind/jaxb-api -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.core/jackson-annotations -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-lang/commons-lang -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/joda-time/joda-time -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
            <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
            <version>2.10.10</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <version>1.18.20</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.12.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <extensions>
            <extension>
                <groupId>kr.motd.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>os-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${os-maven-plugin.version}</version>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.8.6</version>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>**/uk/co/andipari/sts/proto/V12Record*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/BurstFilter*</exclude>
                        <exclude>**/KeystoreWriter*</exclude>
                        <exclude>/uk/co/andipari/sts/V12processor/model/**/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>/uk/co/andipari/sts/V12processor/engine/**/*</exclude>
                        <exclude>/uk/co/andipari/sts/V12processor/headers/Lineage*</exclude>
                        <exclude>/uk/co/andipari/sts/V12processor/headers/JMSHeader*</exclude>
                        <exclude>/uk/co/andipari/sts/V12processor/headers/StsHeaders*</exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>report</id>
                        <phase>test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>report</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>check</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>INSTRUCTION</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.85</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>BRANCH</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0.70</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-dependency-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-protoc</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>com.google.protobuf</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>protoc</artifactId>
                                    <version>${protobuf.version}</version>
                                    <classifier>${os.detected.classifier}</classifier>
                                    <type>exe</type>
                                    <overWrite>true</overWrite>
                                    <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}</outputDirectory>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${maven-antrun-plugin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>exec-protoc</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <configuration>
                            <target>
                                <property name="protoc.filename"
                                          value="protoc-${protobuf.version}-${os.detected.classifier}.exe"/>
                                <property name="protoc.filepath" value="${project.build.directory}/${protoc.filename}"/>
                                <chmod file="${protoc.filepath}" perm="ugo+rx"/>
                                <mkdir dir="${protobuf.output.directory}"/>
                                <path id="protobuf.input.filepaths.path">
                                    <fileset dir="${protobuf.input.directory}">
                                        <include name="**/*.proto"/>
                                    </fileset>
                                </path>
                                <pathconvert pathsep=" " property="protobuf.input.filepaths"
                                             refid="protobuf.input.filepaths.path"/>
                                <exec executable="${protoc.filepath}" failonerror="true">
                                    <arg value="-I"/>
                                    <arg value="${protobuf.input.directory}"/>
                                    <arg value="--java_out"/>
                                    <arg value="${protobuf.output.directory}"/>
                                    <arg line="${protobuf.input.filepaths}"/>
                                </exec>
                            </target>
                        </configuration>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>run</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>build-helper-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>add-integration-test-source</id>
                        <phase>generate-test-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>add-test-source</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <sources>
                                <source>src/it/groovy</source>
                            </sources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <!-- spring-boot-maven-plugin -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.gmavenplus</groupId>
                <artifactId>gmavenplus-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.12.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSources>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>src/test/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                                <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                        <testSource>
                            <directory>src/it/groovy</directory>
                            <includes>
                                <include>**/*IT.*</include>
                            </includes>
                        </testSource>
                    </testSources>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>compile</goal>
                            <goal>compileTests</goal>
                            <goal>addTestSources</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.8.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <release>11</release>
                    <source>11</source>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <!-- update compiler plugin dependency on ASM for Java 11 compatibility -->
                        <groupId>org.ow2.asm</groupId>
                        <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                        <version>9.2</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/test/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
                    <useFile>false</useFile>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*Spec.*</include>
                        <include>**/*Test.*</include>
                    </includes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
                <configuration>
                    <testSourceDirectory>src/it/groovy</testSourceDirectory>
                    <includes>
                        <include>**/*IT.*</include>
                    </includes>
                    <failIfNoTests>true</failIfNoTests>
                    <skipITs>false</skipITs>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>integration-test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>integration-test</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                    <execution>
                        <id>verify</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>verify</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>build-image</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openrewrite.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>rewrite-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>5.22.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <activeRecipes>
                        <recipe>org.openrewrite.java.spring.boot3.UpgradeSpringBoot_3_2</recipe>
                    </activeRecipes>
                </configuration>
                <dependencies>
                    <dependency>
                        <groupId>org.openrewrite.recipe</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rewrite-spring</artifactId>
                        <version>5.4.0</version>
                    </dependency>
                </dependencies>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Does look like this has anything to do with Spring for Apache Kafka or Spring at all. Please, be careful when you add tags to your questions.

Comment: @Tim pom.xml added to the question. Any help regarding the question is much appreciated

Comment: Thanks for sharing your pom.xml; I don't see any reason why that wouldn't just work. Are you using `mvn rewrite:run` with the above? Are you seeing any errors or warnings in the logs when you do?

Comment: Hi @Tim, thanks for the reply.

I'm getting [WARNING] for the trivial syntax changes that the dryRun creates in the rewrite.patch file like I mentioned in the question. Other than that no errors.

`mvn rewrite:run` just applies the simple changes to the source code. There is NO Spring upgrade, Java upgrade, however. Are you sure the openrewrite framework is equipped to work with - Cloud streams, Spring for Apache Kafka etc?

Comment: There should be no such limitations, so I'm puzzled as to why you're not seeing any results. What command are you running?

Comment: I've tried:
 `mvn rewrite:dryRun`, `mvn rewrite:dryRun -f pom.xml`, `mvn rewrite:run`

All yield the same result, NO Spring updates - @Tim